# Install virtualbox on kali linux USB

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, kali-linux

This might be a stupid question, but would it be possible to install Virtual Box or any VM with Kali Linux USB. I have a USB 3 with 64gb of storage running Kali Linux 2018.4, I've also got persistence running with 50 GB of free memory and i'd like to know whether we can run VMs on a bootable device, this way you can have a portable VM and Kali OS at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have persistence working, then you should be able to download and run VirtualBox as normal. I do not recommend this however - as from past experience, I have noticed severe lagging when working with USB persistent devices. This means you are writing to the USB as you would be to disk, which is much much slower. Accessing even small files can take a second or two more than normal, let alone an entire virtualised container of another OS - It might be convenient to do so but it will be much slower than a disk install of Kali. You are welcome to test it out but speed is a common problem. You don't see this on Live USBs because changes are written to RAM instead, though as you know, you lose it all after a reboot when RAM clears.

Another issue is that, while in theory it would work, plugging the live USB into another computer that may not have virtualisation (VT-x) enabled will prevent the virtual OS from working.

On a normal disk install of Kali on one computer, you typically won't have any of these problems. I therefore suggest you dual-boot Kali with your normal OS. I currently do this and have no problems whatsoever, although I haven't virtualised anything on Kali yet. I do use VirtualBox on my normal Xubuntu install so it should work in theory I guess.